# Object with methods command and query should be mock or stub?

Tags: java, spock

I have one question.

I have class which is dependent on other DAO object. DAO object contains two methods: command method and query method. Method which I want test invokes both methods.

Should I mock this object or stub?

I will show you how looks my test.

```
class RentServiceTest extends Specification {
Map<Integer, Room> rooms = new HashMap<Integer, Room>();

def setup() {
    rooms.put(1, new Room(1));
    rooms.put(2, new Room(2));
    rooms.put(3, new Room(3));
    rooms.put(4, new Room(4));
}

def "it should rent concrete room" () {
    given:
        RoomDAO roomDAOMock = Mock();
        RentService rentService = new RentServiceImpl(roomDAOMock);
    when:   
        roomDAOMock.getRooms() >> rooms;
        rentService.rentRoom(2);
    then:   
        1* roomDAOMock.editRoom(_);
        roomDAOMock.getRooms() == rooms;                    
    }
}
```

Test is failed beacuse a method getRooms returns null;

Comment: If you found my answer useful please accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The following test works perfectly fine:

```
@Grab('org.spockframework:spock-core:0.7-groovy-2.0')
@Grab('cglib:cglib-nodep:3.1')

import spock.lang.*

class RentServiceTest extends Specification {
    Map<Integer, Room> rooms = new HashMap<Integer, Room>();

    def setup() {
        rooms.put(1, new Room(1));
        rooms.put(2, new Room(2));
        rooms.put(3, new Room(3));
        rooms.put(4, new Room(4));
    }

    def "it should rent concrete room" () {
        given:
            RoomDAO roomDAOMock = Mock()
            RentService rentService = new RentServiceImpl(roomDAOMock)
        when:   
            roomDAOMock.getRooms() >> rooms
            rentService.rentRoom(2)
        then:   
            1 * roomDAOMock.editRoom(_)
    }
}

class Room {
    Room(int number) {}
}

class RoomDAO {
    def editRoom(int number) {
    }
}

interface RentService {

}

class RentServiceImpl implements RentService {

    RoomDAO dao

    RentServiceImpl(RoomDAO dao) {
        this.dao = dao
    }

    def rentRoom(int number) {
        dao.editRoom(number)
    }
}
```

In general you should use `Mock`.